# Bootstrap4Xpages Forms: Layout in 'read mode' not aligned

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I'm using Domino 9.0.1 and have managed to install correctly the Bootstrap Library 1.0.0.201403171254.

I am now trying to use the Bootstrap Form for my application (a very simple CRUD with edit and delete). I have inspired myself with the code from the 'form' XPage in the Bootstrap4XPages-Demos database.

As far as I can tell, there are some controls that have been 'bootstrapified' and some others where you have to surround your Xpages tag with a div with the bootstrap class you're looking for - and I am not sure where this is documented (if at all).

The issue I have now is that my 'form' doesn't align nicely when in read mode

[image]

but well when in edit mode

[image]

Is there an attribute that I am not setting right (I've posted part of the code below) or was Bootstrap4Xpages never designed with this in mind (i.e. I will have to do separate versions of the markup for 'read' mode and 'edit' mode)?

I'm also suspecting that I am stuck in my Notes Client development mode of thinking, i.e. read mode, edit mode, with old ideas for the UI, so if you have a better alternative please tell me!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument
        var="document1"
        formName="Kurs"
        computeWithForm="onsave">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
<div
    class="row">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            <xp:label
                value="Titel:"
                id="label1"
                for="titel1"
                styleClass="control-label col-sm-2">
            </xp:label>
            <div
                class="col-sm-10">
                <xp:inputText
                    value="#{document1.Titel}"
                    id="inputText1"
                    required="true">
                    <xp:this.validators>
                        <xp:validateRequired
                            message="Geben Sie bitte einen Titel ein"></xp:validateRequired>
                    </xp:this.validators>
                </xp:inputText>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the markup in read mode:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="view:_id1:_id2:_id5:label1" for="view:_id1:_id2:_id5:titel1" class="control-label col-sm-2">Titel:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <span id="view:_id1:_id2:_id5:inputText1">Thailändische Küche 1</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the markup in edit mode:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="view:_id1:_id2:_id5:label1" for="view:_id1:_id2:_id5:titel1" class="control-label col-sm-2">Titel:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" value="Thailändische Küche 1" id="view:_id1:_id2:_id5:inputText1" name="view:_id1:_id2:_id5:inputText1" aria-required="true" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap forms are IMHO not intended to have labels beside the form controls but above. So if you want to layout them both with the col-sm-* classes I'd suggest you to wrap them in divs with that classes or even tables. Also make sure you use the right classes for e.g. a desktop app. The col-sm-* classes are for small resolutions. Add the col-lg-* classes as well as they are designed for the higher resolutions.
BTW: to solve the issue with the richtext editor looking like crap have a look here:

http://mardou.dyndns.org/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=BC2

or for anything else "bootstrap"-ed
http://mardou.dyndns.org/hp.nsf/search.xsp?query=bootstrap

Comment: Hi Oliver, if I look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms there is an example for 'horizontal forms' which uses the same classes as Mark used in his example and which I have posted here. Putting the labels above the forms is a good idea, but would be more a workaround than an answer to my question. I would argue that the read mode/edit mode is going to be pretty standard in most applications, so if the bootstrap 'horizontal form' does not work it should be removed from the demo database. Thanks for the hint for the richtext editor, that was bugging me but I am doing this one step at a time.

Comment: Ok, then you have to compare both markups in read and edit mode. I guess it's an issue with the markup that is generated for the input element. This is rendered as a span element in read mode and maybe this is a problem in the BS4P plugin that should be reported.

Comment: Oliver, you are right, the input element gets displayed as a span, I have updated my question and sent an email to mark with a request that he looks at it. For the moment I'm tempted by your workaround (i.e. put the labels on top)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Bootstrap documentation, there is a class that may suit what you need to do in the http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static section.  When the document is in read mode, the field needs to have a "form-control-static" class, ideally added to a "p" tag (which, generally, doesn't get output by the input control in read mode but you could adapt it for a span if it doesn't work).

Alternatively, you can add your own styling by looking at the markup, as Oliver suggests, and amend your CSS either by adjusting the alignment of the relevant classes or adding padding-top to the label.

Two other suggestions (and I'm sure there many more) are to display the fields in read mode as disabled which will still generate input tags and should maintain the styling of the horizontal-form. Or you could style the read form without using the Bootstrap form markup and edit the content via a dialog interface.

Comment: I mostly solve this by using the 'form-control-static' classes on seperate readonly elements. Not ideal, but it works and you have full control over the output. You can use this approach (http://www.bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/reusableFields.xsp) to make that reusable for all fields.